# Reporting on cases owned by direct reports and other users below.

Tags: reporting

We want to provide an easy way for Supervisors / Managers to report on cases owned by users reporting up to them. Supervisors can select the individual case owners however when their managers need to report on cases owned by each supervisor reporting to them it just becomes impossible for managers to select each individual owners in a report.

Also, we do not want to tie associates to supervisors as it would require a lot of maintenance.

Can someone suggest of some ideas to help us setup our reporting ?

Comment: Have you considered using role hierarchies? In that manner each level can see only the reports information/details that applies to their level.

Comment: Unfortunately, We are not using Role Hierarchy due to some conflict with our business requirements.

Comment: If that's the case, a solution based on private sharing groups would seem to be the only other option that comes to mind which might serve your purposes where you'd have a different group for each level you need to report at.

Comment: Hi crmprogdev, Can you please talk more about the private sharing group solution that you mentioned above ?

Answer (score 1):

If role hierarchy is set proper and you have set OWD as private you can select last option My role Based Team's cases and reports would automatically take care of data pulling .

[image]

Comment: Hi Mohith, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately we are not using Role Hierarchy due to our data security requirements. Can you recommend a different option ?

Comment: If role hirerarchy is not used your only option will be custom reports and Apex SOQL to achieve the same .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Lol this thread is almost 10 years old, but we have just run into exactly the same issue!  Mohith, is this still true i.e you cannot run a report where the owner is in the manager group of the current user?  We have the same situation, which is that the manager group hierarchy is different from the role hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data safety requirements, but by not using roles hierarchies, you've lost one of the most powerful built-in tools available in Salesforce that generally speaking, IMO, enhances data safety if properly applied.

That being said, I've not tried what I'm about to describe and it will involve extra work because you're not using role hierarchies. The first thing you'll need to do is establish easy ways to select your groups. Normally, `User` will have who a User's `Department` is and the `ManagerID` each one reports to. So presumably, you could use `User.ManagerID` to establish your initial groups of `Users` for each `Supervisor`. Whether `Managers` need to see `Supervisors` who don't report to them or not, will determine how you'll set up the private sharing groups. I'm also assuming Supervisors don't need to see Users of Supervisors who don't report to them.

For info on setting up private sharing groups, here are several references. First is [Force.com Platform Fundamentals - Creating on Demand Applications](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf). Others would be [Security Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_overview.htm) and [Tips and Hints for Sharing Cheatsheet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_sharing_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_sharing_cheatsheet/sharing_cheatsheet.htm).

You'll then need to create Custom Reports for each level. One set of Reports for Supervisors and another set for Managers. Depending on how you set up sharing will determine whether you can do those as all in one report or if you'll need to do a template and then run them for each Supervisor and each Manager. Since I don't know your security requirements, I can't advise you in that respect.

Again, the Force.com Platform Fundamentals will be a good resource for you in creating your custom reports. Additional resources would be [Analytics Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_analytics.meta/workbook_analytics/analytics0_intro.htm), [Using the Drag-n-Drop Report Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_report_builder_impl_guide.meta/salesforce_report_builder_impl_guide/report_builder_impl_guide.htm), [Getting Started with Analytics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_analytics_overview_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_analytics_overview_cheatsheet/salesforce_analytics_overview_cheatsheet.htm?language=en), [Report Formula Summary Functions Cheatsheet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_report_summary_functions_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_report_summary_functions_cheatsheet/report_summary_functions_cheatsheet.htm?language=en) and [Maximizing Report Performance Cheatsheet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_reportperformance_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_reportperformance_cheatsheet/reportperformance_cheatsheet.htm?language=en).

I hope this helps you develop a solution that will meet your organization's needs. Sounds like you have a difficult task.